# Exceeding time during csv import

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using the code below (found here on the forum) it basically import a csv file in a google sheet.

Problem is due to the size of my csv I run out of time.
I'm gettin exceeded maximum execution time error.
I've tried it with smaller csvs and it works fine

How can I prevent this?
Are there better ways to import big csv to google sheets?

```js
function importData() {
  var fSource = DriveApp.getFolderById(reports_folder_id); // reports_folder_id = id of folder where csv reports are saved
  var fi = fSource.getFilesByName('report.csv'); // latest report file
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(data_sheet_id); // data_sheet_id = id of spreadsheet that holds the data to be updated with new report data

  if ( fi.hasNext() ) { // proceed if "report.csv" file exists in the reports folder
    var file = fi.next();
    var csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    var csvData = CSVToArray(csv); // see below for CSVToArray function
    var newsheet = ss.insertSheet('NEWDATA'); // create a 'NEWDATA' sheet to store imported data
    // loop through csv data array and insert (append) as rows into 'NEWDATA' sheet
    for ( var i=0, lenCsv=csvData.length; i<lenCsv; i++ ) {
      newsheet.getRange(i+1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
    }
    /*
    ** report data is now in 'NEWDATA' sheet in the spreadsheet - process it as needed,
    ** then delete 'NEWDATA' sheet using ss.deleteSheet(newsheet)
    */
    // rename the report.csv file so it is not processed on next scheduled run
    file.setName("report-"+(new Date().toString())+".csv");
  }
};


// http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1504-Ask-Ben-Parsing-CSV-Strings-With-Javascript-Exec-Regular-Expression-Command.htm
// This will parse a delimited string into an array of
// arrays. The default delimiter is the comma, but this
// can be overriden in the second argument.

function CSVToArray( strData, strDelimiter ) {
  // Check to see if the delimiter is defined. If not,
  // then default to COMMA.
  strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ",");

  // Create a regular expression to parse the CSV values.
  var objPattern = new RegExp(
    (
      // Delimiters.
      "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +

      // Quoted fields.
      "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +

      // Standard fields.
      "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
    ),
    "gi"
  );

  // Create an array to hold our data. Give the array
  // a default empty first row.
  var arrData = [[]];

  // Create an array to hold our individual pattern
  // matching groups.
  var arrMatches = null;

  // Keep looping over the regular expression matches
  // until we can no longer find a match.
  while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec( strData )){

    // Get the delimiter that was found.
    var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[ 1 ];

    // Check to see if the given delimiter has a length
    // (is not the start of string) and if it matches
    // field delimiter. If id does not, then we know
    // that this delimiter is a row delimiter.
    if (
      strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
      (strMatchedDelimiter != strDelimiter)
    ){

      // Since we have reached a new row of data,
      // add an empty row to our data array.
      arrData.push( [] );

    }

    // Now that we have our delimiter out of the way,
    // let's check to see which kind of value we
    // captured (quoted or unquoted).
    if (arrMatches[ 2 ]){

      // We found a quoted value. When we capture
      // this value, unescape any double quotes.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 2 ].replace(
        new RegExp( "\"\"", "g" ),
        "\""
      );

    } else {

      // We found a non-quoted value.
      var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[ 3 ];

    }

    // Now that we have our value string, let's add
    // it to the data array.
    arrData[ arrData.length - 1 ].push( strMatchedValue );
  }

  // Return the parsed data.
  return( arrData );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script includes a loop to insert one row at a time this makes your script slow and to exceed the maximum execution time when importing large CSV files.

Instead of adding one line at a time, try to add all of them a time. If this doesn't work, try to figure out how many lines allow Google Sheets to be added a time. My guess is that it could allow 1000 rows at a time.